# A program that takes a command as input and runs it in the terminal

Tags: bash, go

I kind of know how to do this in C, but how to do it in Go?

This is the code I'm using:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_CMN_LEN 100

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char cmd[MAX_CMN_LEN] = "", **p;

    if (argc < 2) /*no command specified*/
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./program_name terminal_command ...");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
    {
        strcat(cmd, argv[1]);
        for (p = &argv[2]; *p; p++)
        {
            strcat(cmd, " ");
            strcat(cmd, *p);
        }
        system(cmd);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In C, I would do this by simply passing `argc` to `execvp` rather than invoking `system`, which will subject the command the shell interpretation.  Which behavior do you want from `go`?

Comment: @WilliamPursell I want to do the same thing but using GOlang. I have been doing some research and found that it can be done using the ssh package provided by go. But I can't figure out how exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    if len(os.Args) < 2 {
        panic("Usage: ./program_name terminal_command ...")
    }

    cmd := exec.Command(os.Args[1], os.Args[2:]...)
    cmd.Run()
}
```